# Import files to AWS from existing website without downloading them

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have about 20gb of audio files currently residing at Cloudaccess.net and due to storage limits I'm looking at moving them to AWS S3. I've been looking online for a method to transfer these directly from the site to AWS S3 without downloading them but cannot seem to find anything. Is it possible to pull the files in directly or is the only way to download them and then upload them again?

Could anyone provide any advice or possibly provide a link to any resources if this is possible?

Thank you in advance
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS is comprised of many services, and you weren't clear which service you need to upload the files to. I assume you are trying to upload them to S3.

Spin up a temporary EC2 instance, either Linux or Windows, whatever you are most comfortable with. Make sure you specify enough disk space when you spin the instance up. Connect to the EC2 instance and download the files to the EC2 instance using `wget` (Linux) or a web browser (Windows) or whatever tool you like. Once a file is on EC2, copy it to S3. The transfer from EC2 to S3 will be extremely fast.

Comment: Thanks Mark, apologies i've added clarification to the question RE S3 and will give your solution a try and post back :)

Comment: Hi Mark, I've connected and can wget individual files (there are a lot of them) but on the folder i get a 403. Are you aware of anyway round this?

Comment: I don't know what "on the folder I get 403" means. Please provide more information.

Comment: Sorry Mark, when I use the url to the folder I need to copy i.e. wget http://www.example.com/folder I get a 403 forbidden error, but if i specify an exact file i.e. http://www.example.com/folder/file1.mp3 the file transfers successfully.

Comment: You need to write a script that copies one file at a time in a loop.